# Connecting two nodes with horizontal-vertical-horizontal line in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am working on this example: [Simple flow chart](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]
 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (init) {initialize model};
    \node [cloud, left of=init] (expert) {expert};
    \node [cloud, right of=init] (system) {system};
    \node [block, below of=init] (identify) {identify candidate models};
    \node [block, below of=identify] (evaluate) {evaluate candidate models};
    \node [block, left of=evaluate, node distance=3cm] (update) {update model};
    \node [decision, below of=evaluate] (decide) {is best candidate better?};
    \node [block, below of=decide, node distance=3cm] (stop) {stop};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (identify);
    \path [line] (identify) -- (evaluate);
    \path [line] (evaluate) -- (decide);
    \path [line] (decide) -| node [near start] {yes} (update);
    \path [line] (update) |- (identify);
    \path [line] (decide) -- node {no}(stop);
    \path [line,dashed] (expert) -- (init);
    \path [line,dashed] (system) -- (init);
    \path [line,dashed] (system) |- (evaluate);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to remove the "update model" node and to connect directly the decision node node and the "identify..." one with an horizontal-vertical-horizontal line.
I naively tried to use

```
 \path [line] (decide) -|- node [near start] {yes} (identify)
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. See if [Vertical and horizontal lines in pgf-tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45347/110172#110172) helps

Answer (score 12):

The syntax `-|-` is not defined by default, so if you want to use it you need to load [Qrrbrbirlbel's `paths.ortho` library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110172/1952).

Another possibility would be to use the `|-` (or `-|`) syntax. It represents the intersection point between a vertical and a horizontal line. You can find more information at [Flowchart - draw line from node to edge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64386/flowchart-draw-line-from-node-to-edge?rq=1). or [How to draw a return arrow from node-3 to node-1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102385/how-to-draw-a-return-arrow-from-node-3-to-node-1).

Using it, it is easy to draw a connection between `(decide)` and `(identify)`:

```
    \path [line] (decide) --(decide-|expert) |- (identify);
```

`(decide)--(decide-|expert)` draws a line between `decide.center` to the intersection point defined by a horizontal line across `decide.center` and a vertical line across `expert.center`. This line uses `decide.center` as origin, but it will start to be drawn at `decide` border.

`(decide-|expert) |- (identify)` will draw a vertical line with origin at `(decide-|expert)` which will stop at `identify.center` y coordinate. From there a horizonta line will be drawn to the `(identify)` border.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]
 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (init) {initialize model};
    \node [cloud, left of=init] (expert) {expert};
    \node [cloud, right of=init] (system) {system};
    \node [block, below of=init] (identify) {identify candidate models};
    \node [block, below of=identify] (evaluate) {evaluate candidate models};
%    \node [block, left of=evaluate, node distance=3cm] (update) {update model};
    \node [decision, below of=evaluate] (decide) {is best candidate better?};
    \node [block, below of=decide, node distance=3cm] (stop) {stop};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (identify);
    \path [line] (identify) -- (evaluate);
    \path [line] (evaluate) -- (decide);
    \path [line] (decide) --(decide-|expert) |- (identify);
%    \path [line] (update) |- (identify);
    \path [line] (decide) -- node {no}(stop);
    \path [line,dashed] (expert) -- (init);
    \path [line,dashed] (system) -- (init);
    \path [line,dashed] (system) |- (evaluate);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @hardhu. Glad to help you! I'd suggest to read this [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) information and better know how this site works.