# Tikz-Connecting nodes with multiple lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, diagrams, nodes, block

I am trying to reproduce the following image I made in "Power point".

[image]

Although, there is no difficulty in designing the boxes, I find it rather hard to properly position the red and black lines. One solution is to use pure coordinates, but I think that there must be an easiest way to do it, since I have defined nodes.

My code is

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \tikzstyle{blockYellow}=[top color=white, bottom color=yellow!60, draw=yellow!90!black!100, minimum size=1cm, rounded corners]
    \tikzstyle{blockBrown}=[top color=white, bottom color=brown!60, draw=brown!90!black!100, minimum size=1cm, rounded corners]
    \tikzstyle{blockBlack}=[top color=white, bottom color=black!60, draw=black!90!black!100, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=5cm, rounded corners]
    \tikzstyle{blockBlue}=[top color=white, bottom color=blue!60, draw=blue!90!black!100, minimum size=1cm, rounded corners]

    \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
    \pgfsetlayers{background,main}

  %PreAmp
 \node[blockYellow] (PreAmp) {\eng{(Pre)Amp}};
 %Detectors
 \node [blockBrown, left of=PreAmp, node distance=3.5cm, anchor=east] (E2) {$E_2$};
 \node [blockBrown, above of=E2, node distance=2cm] (E1) {$E_1$};
 \node [blockBrown, below of=E2, node distance=2cm] (E3) {$E_3$};
 \node [blockBrown, above of=PreAmp, node distance=3.5cm] (DE2) {$\Delta E_2$};
 \node [blockBrown, left of=DE2, node distance=2cm] (DE1) {$\Delta E_1$};
 \node [blockBrown, right of=DE2, node distance=2cm] (DE3) {$\Delta E_3$};
 %ADC
 \node [blockBlack, right of=PreAmp, node distance=10cm] (ADC) {\textcolor{white}{$ADC$}};
 %Disc
 \node [blockBlue, below of=PreAmp, node distance=5cm] (Disc) {$Discriminator$};
 %FIFO
 \node [blockBlue, right of=Disc, node distance=5cm] (FIFO) {$FIFO$};
 %DGG
 \node [blockBlue, below of=ADC, node distance=5cm] (DGG) {$DGG$};
 %cables
 \draw[red,very thick] (PreAmp)--(Disc);
 %\draw[red,very thick] (PreAmp.north)--(Disc.north);
 \draw[red,very thick] (Disc)--(FIFO);
 \draw[red,very thick] (FIFO)--(DGG);
 \draw[red,very thick] (DGG)--(ADC);
 \draw[very thick] (DE2)--(PreAmp);
 \draw[red, very thick] (E2)--(PreAmp);
 \draw[red, very thick] ($(PreAmp.south west)!0.33!(PreAmp.south east)$)coordinate (a)--(a|-Disc.north);
 \draw[red, very thick] ($(PreAmp.south west)!0.66!(PreAmp.south east)$)coordinate (b)--(b|-Disc.north);
 %\draw[red, very thick] ($(Disc.north east)!0.33!(Disc.south east)$)coordinate (c)--(c|-FIFO.west);
 \draw[red, very thick] ($(Disc.north east)!0.33!(Disc.south east)$) -- ($(FIFO.north west)!0.33!(FIFO.south west)$);
 \draw[red, very thick] ($(Disc.north east)!0.66!(Disc.south east)$) -- ($(FIFO.north west)!0.66!(FIFO.south west)$);
 \draw[very thick] ($(PreAmp.north east)!1/7!(PreAmp.south east)$)--+(0:8.525cm);%(c|-[]ADC.north);%-- ($(ADC.north west)!0.166!(ADC.south west)$);
 \draw[very thick] ($(PreAmp.north east)!2/7!(PreAmp.south east)$)--+(0:8.525cm);
 \draw[very thick] ($(PreAmp.north east)!3/7!(PreAmp.south east)$)--+(0:8.525cm);
 \draw[red, very thick] ($(PreAmp.north east)!4/7!(PreAmp.south east)$)--+(0:8.525cm);
 \draw[red, very thick] ($(PreAmp.north east)!5/7!(PreAmp.south east)$)--+(0:8.525cm);
 \draw[red, very thick] ($(PreAmp.north east)!6/7!(PreAmp.south east)$)--+(0:8.525cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

and my output is

[image]

How to draw the lines using nodes instead of coordinates? I am thinking something like

```
\draw[very thick] (PreAmp.south/3)--(Disc.north/3);
```

i.e. not having to define the line's length, just to connect the two nodes.

**Straight Lines**

**EDIT** After @ClaudioFiandrino 's suggestion on a personal chat  I used the following code to connect the nodes.

```
\draw ($(PreAmp.south west)!0.33!(PreAmp.south east)$)coordinate (a)--(a|-Disc.north);
```

Although this works for the vertical lines, I can't get it to work for the horizontal one because when I use

```
\draw ($(Disc.north east)!0.33!(Disc.south east)$)coordinate (c)--(c|-FIFO.west);
```

I get a vertical line as shown below in the black line. **I insist in using `calc` and `|-` because the nodes in this picture don't have the same dimensions.**

[image]

**"Curved" Lines**

The only way to reproduce the curved lines is to use relative coordinates, but I feel that there must a more convenient way.

So I used

```
%curved cables
 \draw[red, very thick] (E1.east)-- ++(1.3cm,0) -- ++(0,-1.5cm)-- ++(1.3cm,0);%($(PreAmp.north west)!1/3!(PreAmp.south west)$);
 \draw[red, very thick] (E3.east)-- ++(1.3cm,0) -- ++(0,1.5cm)-- ++(1.3cm,0);
 \draw[very thick] (DE3.south)-- ++(0,-1.1cm) -- ++(-1.5cm,0)-- ++(0,-1.15cm);
 \draw[very thick] (DE1.south)-- ++(0,-1.1cm) -- ++(1.5cm,0)-- ++(0,-1.15cm);
```

and the output is

[image]

Comment: You can find valid answers in [High level digital design in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110209/13304).

Comment: @ferahfeza : Thank you very much for your comment. I tried using `\draw ($(PreAmp)!0.33!(Disc)$)--++(-90:0.5);` but this move the line vertically... I don't know how to move it along the x axis. I'll edit my question to illustrate that.

Comment: That's because `(-90:0.5)` says: ''go in direction -90 degrees for 0.5cm''. Note that you're not force to use this syntax. For instance, if you say `\draw ($(PreAmp)!0.33!(Disc)$)--++(-1,0);` that would draw a horizontal line towards left of 1cm. And so on...

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino : I want a vertical line to start at 1/3 of the yellow node. Using this `\draw[very thick] ($(PreAmp)!0.33!(Disc)$)--++(0,-1);` I get a vertical line, but it starts from the center.

Comment: then that code would never work. What you're after is `\draw[very thick] ($(PreAmp.north west)!0.33!(PreAmp.north)$)--++(0,-1);` or south. This is stated in my linked answer.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino : Your code give a line inside the node. I used `\draw[very thick] ($(PreAmp.south)!0.33!(Disc.north)$)--++(0,-1);` but it does the same as `\draw[very thick] ($(PreAmp)!0.33!(Disc)$)--++(0,-1);`. I am seeking for something like `\draw (PreAmp.south/3)--(Disc.north/3)`. The closest to that is `\draw[very thick] ($(PreAmp.south)!0.33!(Disc.north)$)--++(0,-1);` but it doesn't do what I'd expected it to do...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16858/discussion-between-claudio-fiandrino-and-thanos).

Comment: Is `\draw ([xshift=0.5cm]$(PreAmp.south)!0.33!(Disc.north)$)--([xshift=0.5cm]$(PreAmp.north)!0.66!(Disc.north)$);` what you want?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `calc`-library to set the connection-points for your lines. It's a simple approach which should be enough in the most situations. A small MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) [draw, rectangle, minimum height=2cm, minimum width=.5cm] (mynode) {};
  \foreach \y in {-.75,-.5,-.25}{
    \draw [red, ->] (-1,\y) -- ($(mynode.west) +(0,\y)$);
  }
  % ... more lines
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]

Is this information satisfying enough for you or do you need more input?

> Edit: Usage of percentual values depending on nodes
>   The following code uses the `calc`-library to position the line-connectors on an percentual value of the node's edge. (Assumed this from your answer)

**The nodes need the same width/height** to make use of this!

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw, rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm] (PreAmp) {PreAmp};
  \node [draw, rectangle, minimum height=1cm, right=2cm of PreAmp] (ADC) {ADC};
  \node [draw, rectangle, minimum width=3cm, below=1cm of PreAmp] (Disc) {Discriminator};
  \foreach \x in {.25,.5,.75} {
   \draw ($(PreAmp.south west)!\x!(PreAmp.south east)$) -- ($(Disc.north west)!\x!(Disc.north east)$);
   \draw ($(PreAmp.north east)!\x!(PreAmp.south east)$) -- ($(ADC.north west)!\x!(ADC.south west)$);
  }
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]

> To show the two solutions side-by-side: **Relative positioning (1 point) vs. percentual positioning (edge)**

- Blue: percentual positioning on node's edge (the nodes need the same width/height)
- Red:  relative positioning using node's anchors (the node's centers need to be on one axis to make this work)

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw, rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm] (PreAmp) {PreAmp};
  \node [draw, rectangle, minimum height=1cm, right=2cm of PreAmp] (ADC) {ADC};
  \node [draw, rectangle, minimum width=3cm, below=1cm of PreAmp] (Disc) {Discriminator};
  \foreach \x in {.25,.5,.75} {
   % Percentual on node edge
   \draw [ultra thick, blue] ($(PreAmp.south west)!\x!(PreAmp.south east)$) -- ($(Disc.north west)!\x!(Disc.north east)$);
   \draw [ultra thick, blue] ($(PreAmp.north east)!\x!(PreAmp.south east)$) -- ($(ADC.north west)!\x!(ADC.south west)$);
  }
  \foreach \x in {-.25,0,.25} {
   % Relative to one point
   \draw [red] ($(PreAmp.south) +(\x,0)$) -- ($(Disc.north) +(\x,0)$);
   \draw [red] ($(PreAmp.east)  +(0,\x)$) -- ($(ADC.west) +(0,\x)$);
  }
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! What I am trying to avoid is to define the starting and ending coordinates. For instance this would be great `draw (PreAmp.south/3)--(Disc.north/3)` but such a command doesn't exist as far as I know.

Comment: Thank's for your edited answer! I think it is coming to end! Any idea on how to control each line, in order to draw the "curved" lines?

Comment: For this have a look at the `pgfmanual` section 2.4 (Curved Path Construction) or `pgfplots` for plotting functions.

Answer (score 4):

Next code shows another possibility for drawing parallel lines between nodes without using `calc` tikzlibrary. It uses `(node.angle)` syntax for starting points and `|-` or `-|` intersection coordinate for ending ones.

If you want exact coordinates like 1/3 of node's vertical length you need `calc` library, but if you can accept something just visually good enough, can make some test to find the correct `angle`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw, rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm] (PreAmp) {PreAmp};
  \node [draw, rectangle, minimum height=1cm, right=2cm of PreAmp] (ADC) {ADC};
  \node [draw, rectangle, minimum width=3cm, below=1cm of PreAmp] (Disc) {Discriminator};
  \foreach \x in {-7,0,7} {
   \draw [ultra thick, blue] (PreAmp.\x) -- (PreAmp.\x-|ADC.west);
   \draw [red] (PreAmp.\x) -- (PreAmp.\x-|ADC.west);
  }
  \foreach \x in {210,270,330} {
   \draw [ultra thick, blue] (PreAmp.\x) -- (PreAmp.\x|-Disc.north);
  }
  \foreach \x in {250,270,290} {
   \draw [red] (PreAmp.\x) -- (PreAmp.\x|-Disc.north);
  }
    \draw[purple,dashed] (PreAmp.center) -- ++(7:2cm);
    \draw[purple,dashed] (PreAmp.center) -- ++(330:2cm);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The thing is that I want to avoid using lengths and try to use `calc` and intersecting coordinates `-|` and `|-`.

Comment: @Thanos I don't use lengths in my example. `\draw[purple,dashed] (PreAmp.center) -- ++(7:2cm);` is only used to show that top most horizontal path starts at `PreAmp.7`.

Comment: You are right, but using angles, i think it's a bit similar to using lengths i.e. for the starting position of the node.

Comment: @Thanos Sure. In fact I think it's even worse because the distance between parallel lines depends on radius. I just wanted to shown an alternative solution.

Comment: Now I see! It is indeed useful, therefore I voted it up!  Thank you very much for your time and help! Any idea on how to control the lines using intersecting coordinates?

Comment: @Thanos: `|-` is different from `-|`. The first means go up (or down) until intersection between vertical and horizontal lines, while `-|` means go right (or left) until intersection between horizontal and vertical line. Therefore, changes `\draw ($(Disc.north east)!0.33!(Disc.south east)$)coordinate (c)--(c|-FIFO.west);` to `\draw ($(Disc.north east)!0.33!(Disc.south east)$)coordinate (c)--(c-|FIFO.west);` and will get what you want.

Comment: @Thanos: Previous explanation was useful for `\draw` commands but not for coordinates although could be also applied. `c|-FIFO.west` computes intersection between a vertical line from `c.center` and an horizontal one from `FIFO.west` which is different from `c-|FIFO.west`.

Comment: @Thanos More information about `|-` `-|` and similars in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122553/1952 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110172/1952