# shifting an arrow between two blocks up and down

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I need to shift the arrow between two blocks up or down.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=5cm,>=stealth']
\tikzset{
block/.style= {draw, rectangle, minimum height=2em,minimum width=4em},
sum/.style = {draw, circle, node distance=2cm},
input/.style  = {coordinate},  
output/.style = {coordinate}}

\node [block] (A) {};
\node [block, right of=A] (B) {};
\draw [->] (A) -- node {} (B);

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `[yshift=3pt]`?

Comment: You may also want to have a look to [Tikz-Connecting nodes with multiple lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199065/13304). IMHO, to exploit the `calc` library is better if you are already using canvas transformations somewhere else in the picture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The arrow can be moved by a canvas transformation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=5cm,>=stealth']
\tikzset{
block/.style= {draw, rectangle, minimum height=2em,minimum width=4em},
sum/.style = {draw, circle, node distance=2cm},
input/.style  = {coordinate},
output/.style = {coordinate}}

\node [block] (A) {};
\node [block, right of=A] (B) {};
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={yshift=.7em}]
  \draw [->] (A) -- node {} (B);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The length of the arrow (or lines) can be modified by `shorten <` and `shorten >`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=5cm,>=stealth']
\tikzset{
block/.style= {draw, rectangle, minimum height=2em,minimum width=4em},
sum/.style = {draw, circle, node distance=2cm},
input/.style  = {coordinate},
output/.style = {coordinate}}

\node [block] (A) {};
\node [block, right of=A] (B) {};
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={yshift=.7em}]
  \draw [->, shorten <=5mm, shorten >=5mm] (A) -- node {} (B);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result, shortened arrow line]

**Remark:**

- Inside `\resizebox` TeX is in horizontal mode. Therefore spaces matter and
  the unwanted spaced by line ends need to be removed, e.g. by adding the comment character at the end of line.

Comment: how to change the length as well?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you @Heiko Oberdiek so much.